# Xcode11 beta linker error related with fork function

Tags: ios, xcode, fork, beta

I have mongoose server in my iOS app, which call fork() system function:

```
if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
    // Parent
    send_http_error(conn, 500, http_500_error, "fork(): %s", strerror(ERRNO));
  }
```

Started from Xcode 11 beta I can't build the project. I see the following linker error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> **"___gcov_flush", referenced from: _spawn_process in mongoose.o**
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tried comment fork() function and error disappeared.